# How to underline some words using angular?

Tags: angular, string, pipe, angular8

I need to transform into `<a>` (html link) all the words starting with "@".
I'm using angular 8 and I think the best option is using a custom pipe.

Example: if the phrase is "Hello, @test" -> "Hello, `<a href="...">Test</a>`

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd agree that a pipe would probably be best suited to the task.

Assuming you already know how to build pipes, you just need to do something like:

```js
  transform(value: string): string {
    const words = value.split(' '); // Split by spaces
    words.forEach((word) => {
      if(word[0] === '@') {
      // do something like wrap it in a span tag with styling
    }
    return words.join(' ');
  }
```